# Silverstripe error with Subsites module: field called 'CopyToSubsiteID' appears twice

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have installed Silverstripe and Subsites module for multiple domains. Also I've configured such Subsites:

- Main Site
- International
- Latvian

Main site have all the content and International and Latvian have Subsite Virtual pages to Main site.

Also I have the menu:

- About *(AboutPage)*
- Products *(ProductHolderPage)*

  - Foo Large *(ProductPage)*
  - Bar Small *(ProductPage)*

Whenever in backend (admin) I try to go to Main site -> Foo Large or Bar Small the CMS gives me this error:

> [User Error] SilverStripe\Forms{closure}() I noticed that a field
>   called 'CopyToSubsiteID' appears twice
>
> Line 175 in /var/www/foobar_site/vendor/silverstripe/framework/src/Forms/FieldList.php

Notes:
Error also occurs if I want to create new ProductPage.
No problems encountered if visiting any other backend page or any frontend page including ProductPage's.

Any thoughts or guesses or experience with Subsites?

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by having [subsites' extensions](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-subsites/blob/2.3.3/_config/extensions.yml) applied more than once to a class hierarchy - for example, Subsites applies its `SiteTreeSubsites` extension to `SiteTree`. If you then apply it to `Page`, or any child class of it, you may get this error.